# Dynamic element in Jade with String and a variable

Tags: javascript, templates, pug

I have a variable for example named "elem" , "elem" may be head, body and foot;

I want to create html element with for example;

```
if elem == "body"
  "t" + elem => tbody html element 
if elem == "head"
  "t" + elem => thead html element 
if elem == "foot"
  "t" + elem => tfoot element
```

I tried many combination but not able to that. How can implement this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (I assume `elem = "foot"` in this case):

```
- var tag = "t" + elem;
table
  thead
  tbody
  #{tag}
```

should render:

```
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
  <tfoot></tfoot>
</table>
```

But keep in mind this table is not html conform. It's just for demonstration.